# Python waiting for subprocess to finish

Tags: python, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, raspbian, libgphoto2

I'm really new to Python and I got a little problem with the subprocess class.

I'm starting an external Program with :

```
      thread1.event.clear()
      thread2.event.clear()
      print "Sende Motoren STOP"
      print "Gebe BILD in Auftrag"
      proc = Popen(['gphoto2 --capture-image &'], shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
      sleep (args.max+2)
      thread1.event.set()
      thread2.event.set()
      sleep (args.tp-2-args.max)
```

My Problem is that in my shell where I Started the Python script, I still get the outputs of `GPHOTO2` and I think Python is still waiting for GPHOTO to finish.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you **expect** to happen?

Comment: i just want to call gphoto and then without waiting anything go to the sleep command

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `subprocess.Pope` states:

```
stdin, stdout and stderr specify the executed programs' standard
input, standard output and standard error file handles, respectively.
[...]
With None, no redirection will occur; the child's file handles will be
inherited from the parent.
```

So you might want to try something along the lines of this. Which btw. blocks until completion. So you might not need the `sleep()` (here the `wait()` from subprocess.Popen might be want you want?).

```
import subprocess

ret_code = subprocess.call(["echo", "Hello World!"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE);
```

Comment: Well, the problem is that the function gphoto always needs a different time for execution (exposure time) but the codelines above should always take nearly the same time.